# "Cause unwholesome inspiration and impact on viewers"

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

So I have this sentence, and I don't know if you can say "cause" or if I should replace it with another word.

Thank you,
thegirlinneedofhelp

Comment: In spoken English, yes. Whereas, if it is written academically, no.

Comment: It's for my speaking oral exams - will it work for that?

Comment: Unless it's interpreted as an imperative, there is no subject, so it's only a sentence fragment. (Who or what causes that?)

Comment: Oh, sorry - I'll write the full sentence here: "Could she cause unwholesome inspiration and impact on viewers?"

Comment: Could I use that one?

Comment: Oh so it's not the shortened word of "because", anyway, that works fine (correct).